# JSPM GitHub credencial fails

Tags: node.js, github, proxy, authorization, jspm

I try to install Aurelia Tutorial of skeleton-navigation from Aurelia.io.
I have installed Node.js, configured proxy and installed JSPM package.

After this, I try to set credencial to GitHub by executing "jspm registry config github" command, and it always fail.

```
err  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1000:19)
```

In home I have not any problems to set credencial and download data from GitHub.

I tried to init jspm package, using "jspm init" command, but I get many errors like this:

```
warn Error on download for github:ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader
     Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
         at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
         at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1000:19)

err  Error downloading loader files.

err  undefined
```

Did JSPM also need to config proxy ? And how ?

Comment: Try to set environment variables `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY`

Comment: Now I got this: err  Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOU
ND 3128
         at ClientRequest.onError (C:\Users\Tomek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\jspm\node_modules\jspm-github\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\
index.js:168:17)
         at ClientRequest.g (events.js:199:16)
         at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:107:17)
         at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:271:9)
         at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
         at net.js:940:16
         at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

Comment: now it tells that there is no such address that you pass to env variables.

Comment: I added http:// prefix and it seems, that ssl protocol is disabled ?        err  Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO 101057
795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\
ssl\s23_clnt.c:782:

Comment: O ! It works. I just removed from environment HTTPS_PROXY and it passed. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

To change proxy server of jspm, there was needed to set `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else makes this stupid mistake (that I did).

On Windows, setting the environment variable HTTP_PROXY is not just `set HTTP_PROXY=something`. It can probably be done on the command line, but it's also easy to do via the system prefs. window. (just google *windows set environment variable*).

The hard part is not to set the env. variable, it is that so many examples on the web are for Linux, so it is easy to forget (and then nothing works).

By the way, setting this solved my *jspm* problem (ECONNRESET), and I'm behind a company proxy.